# RegEx pattern to match between nth and mth occurence of a word

Tags: regex

I have some example String like :

```
There is one wherever you one and here is the one , nowhere is the one .
```

I want to extract between the second `one` and the third `one` , that is, `and here is the`

I am not sure how to position my patterns accordingly .. Can any one help ?

Comment: What language are you using?  Most likely, it has a `split` function that you can use to split the string by `one` into an array, and then join the indexes that you want.

Comment: I am working on Java. I have used the split method .. But can we not do it using only RegEx . Using Split method, the Line of Code increases ..

Answer (score 1):

[\K](http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/) is so under-appreciated

```
grep -oP '^(.*?one){2}\K.*?(?=one)' \
     <<< "There is one wherever you one and here is the one , nowhere is the one"
and here is the
```